# Batch Loop array of file extensions

Tags: arrays, batch-file, command-line, command, batch-processing

I am trying to loop through an array of file extensions I was able to get it to target the first extension but changed the code and now I can't remember what I did. Regardless the code I am using doesn't loop through the array of extensions. If you can explain with reference to links that aided to an answer.

```
    :: ACTION :: 1 CLEAN
:cleanup
    set "Fdocs=%CD%\1_docs"
    set "Fphotos=%CD%\2_photos"
    set "Fdesigns=%CD%\3_designs"
    set "Freviews=%CD%\4_reviews"
    set "Ffinal=%CD%\5_final"
    set "$ext="
    set "action=Cleaning"

:: CLEAN :: documents
    set "$ext=.txt .doc .docx .xls .csv .ppt .pptx"
    call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fdocs%"

    cls
    echo %action% project folder.

:: CLEAN :: images
    set "$ext=.jpg .png .tiff .raw .nef .crw .dng"
    call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fphotos%"

    cls
    echo %action% project folder..

:: CLEAN :: designs
    set "$ext=.psd .psb"
    call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fdesigns%"

    set "$ext=.ai .svg .svgz .esp"
    call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fdesigns%"

    set "$ext=.indd .idml"
    call :fMover "%$ext%" "%Fdesigns%"

    cls
    echo %action% project folder...
    echo done.

    goto :intro

:fMover
for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims==" %%G in ('dir /b /s %CD%\*%~1') do (
    rem move %%G %~2
    echo "%%G" %~2
    echo %~2
    rem echo %~1
    timeout 2 >nul
    pause
    goto :eof
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with your :fMover subroutine:

1. You specified "usebackq", but then you did not use back quotes. See FOR /?
2. You need two loops. An outer loop to iterate through list of extensions and an inner loop to enumerate the files in the folder with that extension.

Change your :FMover to this and then make changes as needed from there.

```
:fMover
pause
for /F "tokens=1*" %%G in ('echo.%~1') do (
   echo.  
   echo.Move files with extension=%%G to %~2
   for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%K in (`dir /b /s "%CD%\*%%G"`) do (
      echo %%K
      rem move %%K %~2
   )
   if not "%%H"=="" call :fMover "%%H" "%~2"
)
goto :eof
```

By way of explanation:

1. On each pass through the outer loop %%G contains the first token (extension) and %%H contains all the rest (for later use).
2. The inner loop enumerates the files with that extension.
3. The subroutine then calls itself (recursion) with the 1st argument being %%H (the remaining extensions).
4. Repeat until there are no more extensions in the list.

Some general advice:

1. Save a copy of your code from time to time; especially when you get it working to a degree.
2. Only change a little at a time. Get that working before making other changes.

It can be very frustrating to have something working and then lose it by making too many changes :)

Comment: RGuggisberg, A million thanks for the explanation for some reason I knew I would possibly have to consider using two loops but thought there was a way to circumvent it using a singular loop. Now I understand that wasn't possible. Thank you too for the coding advice I usually am pretty good about small edits, but got really tangled in experimentation with this issue will continue to remind myself good coding habits. Thank you for everything this is definitely a great start. What links have you found useful in learning command / batch scripting btw?

Comment: There is plenty of info on the web. A few sites I find very useful are: http://ss64.org/,  http://ss64.com/nt/, and http://www.robvanderwoude.com/